# CUDA "Access Violation" when access “ __managed__ int ”variables by a host function

Tags: cuda, gpu, nvidia

The problem occurred when I run the "Gipuma" project, which need the support of opencv and CUDA. My Video card is GTX 750Ti，with CUDA 8.0.

It got "Access Violation" when access the "__managed__ int" variables through a host function.In general,a "__managed__"variable can be read and write through both device and host.I am so confused and I think there may be something wrong in Configuration?

The variables declare in "gipuma.cu":

```
#ifndef SHARED_HARDCODED
__managed__ int SHARED_SIZE_W_m;
__constant__ int SHARED_SIZE_W;
__managed__ int SHARED_SIZE_H;
__managed__ int SHARED_SIZE = 0;
__managed__ int WIN_RADIUS_W;
__managed__ int WIN_RADIUS_H;
__managed__ int TILE_W;
__managed__ int TILE_H;
#endif
```

and the host function in "gipuma.cu":

```
int runcuda(GlobalState &gs)
{
    WIN_RADIUS_W = 0;//it gets wrong here,access violation.
    printf("test is %d\n", WIN_RADIUS_W);
    printf("Run cuda\n");

    if(gs.params->color_processing)
        gipuma<float4>(gs);
    else
        gipuma<float>(gs);

    return 0;
}
```

and the error message：

```
0x000000013FA1DCBD has an unhandled exception (in gipuma.exe): 0xC0000005: An access violation occurred when writing to location 0x0000000000000000.
```

Comment: CUDA is not C, nor really C++.

Comment: You need to provide a [mcve].  This [can happen](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#um-simplifying) if you call a kernel and then your host function without an intervening `cudaDeviceSynchronize()`

Comment: Also, make sure you are building this as a 64-bit project.

Comment: Thank you for your advice,but I think the code is fine. Because it's run successful in other compute with the sames step.And the "/__managed__"  variable can be access in other project in this compute.

Comment: BTW,the code was downloaded from https://github.com/kysucix/gipuma.

Answer (score 2):

On devices before compute capability 6.0 host and device may not access `__managed__` memory concurrently, because [the driver needs an opportunity to programmatically copy the data between host and device](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#um-data-migration).

So, As Robert Crovella already pointed out in his comment, you need to insert a call to `cudaDeviceSynchronize()` after a kernel call before being able to access `__managed__` memory from the host again.